# Chrome extension reset overridden function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, navigator, content-script

## The problem:

A chrome extension I am working on needs a location spoofer. It works, however I cannot 'unset' it.

## What I have so far:

Let's examine the relevant code. This is a part of a content script.

```js
let cachedGeoLocFunc = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

let geoSpoofCode = conf => `
  (function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success) { return success(${conf}); }
    } else {
    console.error('Geolocation is not supported in this browser');
    }
  })()
`

browser.runtime
  .sendMessage({ type: 'request-spoofed-coords' })
  .then(curCoords => {
    //json from state, contains current spoofed locale
    if (curCoords) {
      let script = document.createElement('script')
      script.textContent = geoSpoofCode(curCoords)

      document.documentElement.appendChild(script)
      script.remove()
    } else {
      //revert to default behavior
      let unSetScript = document.createElement('script')
      unSetScript.textContent = `
      (function() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = ${cachedGeoLocFunc};
      })()`
      document.documentElement.appendChild(unSetScript)
      unSetScript.remove()
    }
  })
```

As you can see, I am overriding the chrome native function and providing my own value. This works fine for spoofing a location.

## Unexpected behaviour:

Conceptually I imagined this would work. I am **caching** the native chrome function so I can later reset it (see the else). In practice I get this error when this content script gets injected into a page.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

And it breaks here (as per the chrome inspector)

[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7sSe.png)

## My questions!

So, it just injects **[ native code ]** instead of the actual function (at-least that is what it looks like).

Does anyone know how I can **un-override** this function. Is there an elegant way to do this?

How does caching in chrome work, is there ever a way to view this **native code**

Anyways help would be appreciated. Hope you all have a great day!

Comment: Do you know the content script runs in an *isolated world* so all your variables and functions are inaccessible from the page scripts and vice versa? You can't transfer a working link to a function across that boundary. And caching the function in a content script won't help you - you need to save it inside your page script (the code in a script element).

Comment: @wOxxOm Hey! I did not know that -_-, in this case, I believe my question is not entirely valid...

Comment: You can override page functions but you need to do it inside the script element's code as you're doing already. The only change you need is to save the old function also inside that script element's code (in a closure for reliability). To manage the state you can use DOM messaging between your content script and your page script via dispatchEvent/addEventListener with a random generated event name so the site doesn't intercept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a misunderstanding as @wOxxOm pointed out. Please refer to their response. Content scripts do not affect or truly 'override' api functions.